# Why NATS doesn't map subjects?

Tags: nats.io, nats-jetstream

I run a NATS server in Docker

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
services:
  nats:
    container_name: nats-server

    image: 'nats:2.10.9-alpine3.19'

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8222/healthz"]

    ports:
    - "8230:8222" # exposing 8230 to the host
    - "4230:4222" # exposing 4230 to the host

    volumes:
    - "./nats/data/single:/data"
    - "./nats/config:/config"

    command:
    - "--js"
    - "--sd=/data"
    - "--http_port=8222"
    - "--name=nats-server"
    - "--cluster_name=local-cluster"
    - "--config=/config/nats.config"  # !! UPDATED
```

I created a stream

```bash
nats -s localhost:4230 \
  stream add \
  --retention=work \
  --subjects="events.>" eventsw
```

Then I create a mapping

```bash
nats -s localhost:4230 \
    server mapping "events.foo" "events.boo"
```

NATS proposes to test mapping:

```
[local-nats] ? Subject events.foo
events.boo
```

Looks that everything is correct. Then I run two subscribers:

```
nats -s localhost:4230 sub "events.foo"
nats -s localhost:4230 sub "events.boo"
```

and finally I send a message:

```
nats -s localhost:4230 \
  pub "events.foo" \
  ololo
```

And result is coming to an initial subject – `events.foo`. So mapping actually doesn't happen. It was assumed that the message will come to `events.boo`.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject mapping is configured by NATS server config. You can read about it more [here](https://natsbyexample.com/examples/jetstream/partitions/cli).

In short:

1. `docker-compose.yaml` should contain one more `command` line:
   `- "--config=/config/nats.config"`

When you run compose `nats.config` will appear in `./nats/config` folder.

2. config file must be extended with the following section:

```
mappings = {
  # Simple direct mapping.  Messages published to foo are mapped to bar.
  foo: bar

  "events.foo": "events.boo"
}
```

3. Restart NATS.

Now messages published to `events.foo` will be forwarded to `events.boo`.

4. Enjoy.

P.S. [Here] doc says that we can run `nats-server --signal reload` to update server configuration. But I failed with this